# Plotting population density map in R with geom_point

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm working on a simple population density plot of Canada. I have data for population based on postal code and latitude/longitude [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/je1wz2tj9rw8vvj/PopulationDensity.csv?dl=0)

I want to improve the plot to show color change as the density of points increases. This is the code I have:

```
library(maptools)
library(gdata)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(classInt)
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

Canada <- get_map(location="Canada", zoom=3, maptype="terrain")

ggmap(Canada, extent="normal") + geom_point(data=PopDensity, aes(x=LONG,y=LAT,size=POPULATION), 
alpha = 0.3)+scale_size_continuous(range=c(1,6))
```

which produces a plot like

[image: so.]

What I'd really like is a way to keep the data points the same size, but instead of making the points transparent, changing the color as a function of point density.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to calculate the densities first, then assign the values to the points so you can map that aesthetic:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(scales)
library(ggmap)
library(MASS)
library(sp)
library(viridis)

pop <- read.csv("~/Dropbox/PopulationDensity.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# get density polygons
dens <- contourLines(
    kde2d(pop$LONG, pop$LAT, 
          lims=c(expand_range(range(pop$LONG), add=0.5),
                 expand_range(range(pop$LAT), add=0.5))))

# this will be the color aesthetic mapping
pop$Density <- 0

# density levels go from lowest to highest, so iterate over the
# list of polygons (which are in level order), figure out which
# points are in that polygon and assign the level to them

for (i in 1:length(dens)) {
  tmp <- point.in.polygon(pop$LONG, pop$LAT, dens[[i]]$x, dens[[i]]$y)
  pop$Density[which(tmp==1)] <- dens[[i]]$level
}

Canada <- get_map(location="Canada", zoom=3, maptype="terrain")

gg <- ggmap(Canada, extent="normal")
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=pop, aes(x=LONG, y=LAT, color=Density))
gg <- gg + scale_color_viridis()
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="none")
gg
```

[image]

Comment: Where does this take into account the Population value instead of just the long, lat coordinate. Isnt this just representing where points are more/less dense but not the value of the population at each point?